# Constantly updating global variable only printing first value

Tags: python, variables, raspberry-pi, global-variables

I'm trying to display the temperature from a temperature sensor on a 7 segment display. Both are connected to my Raspberry Pi. I need to store the current temperature in a variable, and of course that is always changing.

My problem is that the variable only prints what the temperature is at the point when the script is ran. It does not change as the temperature changes.

```
import os
import time

os.system('modprobe wl-gpio')
os.system('modprobe wl-therm')

temp_sensor = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0316201553ff/w1_slave'

temp_f = 0

def temp_raw():
    f = open(temp_sensor, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines


def read_temp():
    lines = temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = temp_raw()

    temp_output = lines[1].find('t=')
    if temp_output != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1].strip()[temp_output + 2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 // 5.0 + 32.0
        global temp_f
        temp_f = int(temp_f)



read_temp()
while True:
    print(temp_f)
    time.sleep(1)

# Below is what I will eventually need to run in order to display the     digits on my 7-segment display.
'''
while True:
    print( map(int,str(temp_f)) )
    time.sleep(1)
'''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only reading the temperature once and displaying the same value over and over in your `while` loop. You should periodically re-read the temperature inside the loop:

```
while True:
    read_temp()
    print(temp_f)
    time.sleep(1)
```

A larger `sleep` value may help if the temperature read operation requires too much power.

Answer (score 1):

You're only calling `read_temp()` once, and printing the same value on each iteration. Change your loop to this:

```
while True:
    read_temp()
    print(temp_f)
    time.sleep(1)
```

However, global variable usage like this tends to lead to maintainability problems down the road. I'd do it like this:

```
def read_temp():
    lines = temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = temp_raw()

    temp_output = lines[1].find('t=')
    if temp_output != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1].strip()[temp_output + 2:]

        # temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 // 5.0 + 32.0

        return int(temp_f)

while True:
    temp_f = read_temp()
    print(temp_f)
    time.sleep(1)
```